# Picking a threshold from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix named D and I want to choose a particular value from D as a threshold.

D

```
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]       [,6]       [,7]
 [1,] 4.20523 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 [2,] 0.00000 2.161999 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 [3,] 0.00000 0.000000 1.138677 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 [4,] 0.00000 0.000000 0.000000 1.040475 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 [5,] 0.00000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.3852305 0.00000000 0.00000000
 [6,] 0.00000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.04953807 0.00000000
 [7,] 0.00000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.01362526
 [8,] 0.00000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
 [9,] 0.00000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
             [,8]         [,9]
 [1,] 0.000000000 0.000000e+00
 [2,] 0.000000000 0.000000e+00
 [3,] 0.000000000 0.000000e+00
 [4,] 0.000000000 0.000000e+00
 [5,] 0.000000000 0.000000e+00
 [6,] 0.000000000 0.000000e+00
 [7,] 0.000000000 0.000000e+00
 [8,] 0.005127803 0.000000e+00
 [9,] 0.000000000 9.693644e-05
```

I used

which(diag(D)<0.56)

[1] 5 6 7 8 9

It displayed as above. I want to fix the 5th diagonal element as my epsilon. That is, my epsilon = 0.3852305.

I don't want to look at the matrix everytime and fix the epsilon like epsilon=D[5,5].

Also I have tried using ifelse statement

ifelse(D>0 & D<0.5,1,0)

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

From this how can i fix the epsilon value as my threshold?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you always want the middle value of the matrix?

Comment: `i <- which(diag(D) < 0.56))[1] ; epsilon <- D[i,i]`?

Comment: Is it always a diagonal matrix?

Comment: @ catastrophic-failure Yes. It is always a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @ thelatemail Not exactly the middle value. I need the first value in a diagonal matrix which satisfies D< 0.56. For eg. In my D matrix i have 5 diagonal which satisfies <0.56. But I want to pick only first value which satisfies the same not others.

Answer (score 0):

This should return your threshold:

```
thres <- D[which(D>0 & D<0.5, arr.ind = TRUE)][1]
thres
# [1] 0.3852305
```

Comment: Thanks. It displays all the five values. But i need only the first value. Not five values.

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the value then this is enough

```
diag(D)[which(diag(D) < 0.56)][1]
```